# Can I Write noflo Component by C++?

Tags: noflo

I have a local system which is written by C++.

I want to integrate noflo with my system,so I want to write a component(by C++) to fetch data from my system to noflo,and write another component(by C++) to provide data from noflo to my system.

Comment: I want to write a component by C++ to integrate into noflo, I know how to write it by coffeescript,but i can't find a way to write it by C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot *directly* write a NoFlo component in C++, as NoFlo is a JavaScript library.

If you are using NoFlo on Node.js, you can create a [node.js C++ addon](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html), and then use the JS API in your NoFlo component.
If you are using NoFlo on browser, you can use [Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten) to compile your C++ into JS.

Other mechanisms of communicating from a NoFlo program with C++ code include:

- Running the C++ code as a subprocess, and communicate over stdin/stdout. See [gmr-saliency example](https://github.com/the-grid/gmr-saliency/blob/master/components/GetSaliency-node.coffee).
- Communicate between NoFlo and your system using a standard message broker like AMQP or MQTT. [MsgFlo](http://msgflo.org) and [msgflo-cpp](https://github.com/msgflo/msgflo-cpp) is designed created to help with that. **Recommended for distributed systems**.
- Implementing the [FBP runtime protocol](http://noflojs.org/documentation/protocol/) and using noflo-runtime/RemoteSubgraph to communicate with it. Documentation [currently missing](https://github.com/noflo/noflo-runtime/issues/65)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, have a look at the C++ implementation of the FBP protocol:

https://github.com/microflo/microflo

Comment: microflo is a flow engine like noflo which is used inside a microController.But I want to write a component by C++ to integrate into noflo, I know how to write it by coffeescript,but i can't find a way to write it by C++

Comment: Is the rest of your application written in NodeJS?

Comment: the rest of my application written in C++ and C#

Comment: In that case, you can build and embed the (flow) bootstraper as part of your application, and call it from within your application as a function.

The bootstrapper is the piece of code that initiate and run your graph. When you're writing a pure FBP application, it takes the form of the main method. If you want to have a flow-based component in a legacy application, you'll need to write your own bootstrapper, which build a graph, take the input (function parameter) and feed it into the graph, then return the output.

Hope this make sense.

Comment: Maybe I should use csharpfbp instead of noflo